# How to improve the neural networks accuracy?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

Recently I have Implemented Backpropagation on the MNIST dataset using the following code and obtained the overall accuracy of approximately **95.7%**.

My question is how can we further improve the accuracy of the code given below.

I have tried to increase/decrease the number of hidden nodes. Also changing the learning rate to different values but the accuracy isn't going beyond **96%**.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.special 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

k = list()
k_ =list()

class NeuralNetworks:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate ):

        self.inodes = inputnodes

        self.hnodes = hiddennodes

        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0 , pow(self.hnodes , -0.5),(self.hnodes, self.inodes))

        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0 , pow(self.onodes , -0.5),(self.onodes , self.hnodes))

        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        pass

    def train(self, input_list, target_list):
        
        inputs = np.array(input_list , ndmin = 2).T 
        targets = np.array(target_list , ndmin =2).T

        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih , inputs)

        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who , hidden_outputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        output_errors = targets - final_outputs

        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

        self.who += self.lr*np.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1 - final_outputs)), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))

        self.wih += self.lr*np.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs *(1 - hidden_outputs)), np.transpose(inputs))

        pass


    def query(self, input_list):
        
        inputs = np.array(input_list , ndmin = 2).T 

        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih , inputs)
        
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who , hidden_outputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs

input_nodes = 784   

hidden_nodes = 300

output_nodes = 10

learning_rate = 0.2

n = NeuralNetworks(input_nodes , hidden_nodes , output_nodes , learning_rate)

train_data_f = open("C:\Python27\mnist\mnist_train.csv" , 'r')

train_data_all = train_data_f.readlines()

train_data_f.close()

for rec in train_data_all:

    all_val = rec.split(',')

    inputs = (np.asfarray(all_val[1:])/255.0*.99) + 0.01

    targets = np.zeros(output_nodes) + 0.01

    targets[int(all_val[0])] = 0.99

    n.train(inputs , targets)


test_data_f = open("C:\Python27\mnist\mnist_test.csv" , 'r')

test_data_all = test_data_f.readlines()

test_data_f.close()



for rec in test_data_all:

    all_val = rec.split(',')

    p = (n.query((np.asfarray(all_val[1:])/255*.99)+0.01))

    k.append(list(p).index(max(list(p))))

    k_.append(int(all_val[0]))

print confusion_matrix(k_ , k)

print np.trace(np.asarray(confusion_matrix(k_ , k)))/10000.0
```

The output of the above code is (Confusion Matrix & Overall Accuracy):

```
 Confusion Matrix-
 [[ 965    0    1    0    0    1    9    0    3    1]
 [   0 1126    2    1    0    1    2    0    3    0]
 [   8    4  958   19    1    1    6   10   22    3]
 [   1    0    2  982    0    5    1    4    9    6]
 [   3    0    4    0  923    0    9    0    3   40]
 [   3    3    0   14    1  843   11    0   12    5]
 [   7    3    0    0    3    9  935    0    1    0]
 [   4   16    5    1    3    1    1  952    2   43]
 [   3    3    1   12    6    8    8    5  920    8]
 [   4    7    0    8    8    2    2    3    8  967]]

 Overall Accuracy is 0.9571
```

Here's the plot:

[image: Plot For Learning Rate]

Comment: reproducible data set?  Also, why do you believe that accuracy greater than 96% is achievable using this technique?

Comment: @ C8H10N4O2 Ok that's fine... one cannot achieve that high accuracy.Why it can't be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing/Decreasing hidden layers, changing learning rate, trying with different activation functions or modifying the number of epochs to train your neural network won't work out in most of the cases. Rather, try to focus on reducing the error rate of your neural network. Train Your network with a possible number of input data may help you to achieve accuracy in a better way.

Also, Feature Extraction here plays a vital role. Before Classification of MNIST data, apply the best feature extraction technique to improve classification rate of your network.

For an instance, I attached an URL below this answer. In that paper, they achieved 99.67% of accuracy rate for MNIST dataset. They used MLP for classification and Multiple Feature Selection Technique. Have a look into this.

------------------->        [Link is attached here](https://www.academia.edu/4262124/Handwritten_Digit_Recognition_Using_Multiple_Feature_Extraction_Techniques_and_Classifier_Ensemble)

Answer (score 2):

### If the learning rate is too big means steps may be too large, and we might step over potential optimums or even bounce out of an optimum.

[image]

1. You should dive deeper in [Andrew Ng's Coursera Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/3iawu/gradient-descent-in-practice-ii-learning-rate) 
   to fully understand the fundamental ML knowledges.
2. Second, better use Convolutional Neural Networks to extract more features, that will increase you accuracy.

Once you learn CNN technique, you probably know some useful skills **[dropout](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf)**, **pooling**, **relu activation** ...etc.

Comment: I am done with coursera Andrew NG course...Now trying to convert everything in Python...

Comment: Learning rate between.1 to .4 is apt as recommended in the Bishops book for ANN